# How to insert...on duplicate key update (MySQL) after a condition same as IF() condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert, on-duplicate-key

I am implementing a situation when the INSERT ...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE needs to be executed **only after an IF condition is satisfied**.
I am having issues on how to include the condition statement. _Without this IF condition the mysql query is working fine. I tried WHERE statement but insert...on duplicate key update doesn't support WHERE statement.

*Please guide me a work around for this*.

The implementation flow is like this:

> table1
> *PRIMARY KEY(SL_No,unique_address)*

```
SL_No| Unique_Addres| hostname| Address|
1| 20211001|Peter Rick|   Ohio|
2| 20211011|     Rowan| London|
3| 20211019|      Lily|  Perth|
```

> table2
> *PRIMARY KEY(fk_id,unique_address)
> FOREIGN KEY (unique_address) REFERS table1(unique_address)*

```
fk_id| Unique_Address| Check_in| Check_out|
20-10-01|  20211001|  15:00|  16:00|
20-12-12|  20211011|  09:39|   NULL|
```

New unique entries with unique addresses e.g. (fk_id, 'KEY') should be inserted in the table2 **only after verifying that the 'KEY' is already registered in table1**. Else, reject the entry and don't enter it in table2.
After the verification,

insert values('fk_id','KEY','value',null)(if the entry is not present in table2)
or

update(?,?,?,value)(if the entry is already present in table2).

For example,

```
INSERT INTO table2('21-02-12','202111012','15:13',DEFAULT)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Check_out` = '15:13';
--This query above should not execute 
--because unique_address '202111012' is not in table1


#Pseudo query
SET @KEY = '20211011', @dat ='20-12-12',@tim = '18:10'
IF EXISTS(@KEY in (SELECT table1.unique_address FROM table1))
{
    INSERT INTO table2 (fk_id,unique_address,col1,col2)
    VALUES(@dat, @KEY,@tim, DEFAULT)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = @tim;
}
ELSE
{
    RETURN;
  --do nothing or skip to next iteration( if inside a loop)
}
```

The pseudo query above should update 2nd row of table2 and it should look like this:

```
fk_id| Unique_Address| Check_in| Check_out|
20-10-01|  20211001|  15:00|  16:00|
20-12-12|  20211011|  09:39|  18:10|
```

How to proceed to get the desired result? It doesn't matter if I use a WHERE clause or an IF EXISTS() clause as long as I am getting the desired result.

**Edit:-**

I came up with a possible solution.

```
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `table2`(`fk_ID`, `Unique_Address`, `Check_in`, `Check_out`) 
    VALUES ( 
            '20-12-25',
           (SELECT table1.Unique_Address from table1 WHERE table1.Unique_Address = '20211089'),
            '15:19',
            DEFAULT) 
    on duplicate key UPDATE `Check_out` = '15:19';
```

I got the desired result with the above query. but in case of an un-registered unique_address a new row was entered with empty Unique_Address cell. Like this:

```
fk_id| Unique_Address| Check_in| Check_out|
20-10-01|  20211001|  15:00|  16:00|
20-12-12|  20211011|  09:39|  18:10|
20-12-13|          |  15:19|   NULL|
```

Is there any other efficient way of doing this so that there is no such empty cell (empty Unique_Address cell)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I tried WHERE statement but insert...on duplicate key update doesn't support WHERE statement.* Only in VALUES variation. `INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` have no such restriction.

Comment: @Akina can a condition be applied using SELECT.. WHERE.. in the middle? I'm not able to visualize it, can you please provide some reference for clarity?  SELECT only returns something based on the conditions specified in WHERE, right?  I wanted to implement If(condition ) THEN statement.

Comment: Unclear. Show an example: CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO with some sample data, additional criteria which must be used, desired final data state, detailed explanations which refers to separate rows and values.

Comment: @Akina I have revised the problem explanation. Please check.